# Unable to find out which FMU has error in fmpy

Tags: python, fmi

I simulated a batch of 5 FMUs by putting a function containing the fmpy simulate in a loop.
4 of them simulate correctly. The fifth one due to a wrong parameter shows an error.

My question is, is there any way to find out in which FMU the error comes during simulation

Ideally the output should look like:
FMU1: OK
FMU2: OK
FMI3: 'Error' and so on

```
def wf(i):
    result = simulate_fmu(
        fmupath[i],
        validate=False,
        start_time=0,
        stop_time=endtime,
        solver='CVode',
        output_interval=stepsize,
        record_events=False,
        start_values = parameters[i],
        output = resultvariables,
    )
    dfindres = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
    return dfindres

results = [wf(i) for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the exception and return the status message together with the result like so

```py
def wf(i):
    try:
        result = simulate_fmu(
            fmupath[i],
            validate=False,
            start_time=0,
            stop_time=endtime,
            solver='CVode',
            output_interval=stepsize,
            record_events=False,
            start_values=parameters[i],
            output=resultvariables,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return None, "FMU%d: Error" % i

    dfindres = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
    return dfindres, "FMU%d: OK" % i

# list of tuples (result, status)
results = [wf(i) for i in range(5)]
```